# Are Custom Indexes passed on to Sandboxes

Tags: sandbox, custom-index

Are "Customer Support Enabled" custom indexes also pulled into Sandboxes? I cannot find documentation about this.

*Note: I am NOT asking about user-defined custom indexes.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_indexes.htm) says so below:

[image]

Comment: thank you! can't believe I missed that :)

Comment: +1 for the hand-drawn red line.